# MySQL search and replace specific character combinations

Tags: mysql, json

NOTE: This is hilarious - I've had to update this post multiple times because it doesn't properly display combinations of the \ character :)

I need to be able to search and replace a specific set of characters without compromising specific allowed combinations or the redundancy of those characters. Let's take a core escape character \ for example.

A string that needs processing may look like this:

```
"This is \ a test! \\r\\n Let's have \r \n \\\ Some fun!"
```

Now I need to address each \ for translation to JSON (each \ needs to be \\\\), but at the same time, I don't want to touch the \r or \n. I also want to be able to differentiate between \r and \n vs \r and \n. Is there a method using REGEXP I could adopt that would take the above and convert it to:

```
"This is \\\\ a test! \\r\\n Let's have \\r \\n \\\\\\\\\\\\ Some fun!"
```

Note I want each escape \ to be 4x \, and also to ensure special escaped characters are double escaped, but not compound them (the 4x only needs to be applied to stand alone \'s).

What it comes down to is I can't control the data that's coming in, but I can control scrubbing it. I could get weird data with \/////\ by somebody who was just having fun. I need to be able to scrub that as a TEXT value and prepare it for insertion into the database via a dynamically created SQL statement that's executed, which means a single \ needs to be \\\\ and the / is ignored (for example).

I'm thinking I first need to do a specific scan of special escape sequences (such as \', \b, \\, \r, etc.) but at the same time verify they aren't already double escaped. I need need to ensure the additional scans of \ don't meet any special standards (and are just escaped on their own).

I'm hoping somebody has already dealt with this and there's an existing function or SP designed to do this sort of thing so I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I also want to be able to differentiate between **\r and \n** vs **\r and \n**."* I do not see the difference. *".. would take the above and convert it to .."* Both `\r \n` and `\\r \\n` results in `\\r \\n` - is it safe? PS. Does some symbols which are absent in source string with guarantee exists?

Comment: Sorry @Akina I'm not following your question? What I mean is if I'm to build a mechanism of scrubbing the text, I can't break specific escape sequences. Part of this issue is I'm dealing with two sets of rules - the MySQL JSON Escape Rules and then the MySQL TEXT Escape Rules (both are different). This creates compounded complexity, which is what I'm trying to deal with -- how to simplify things.